# How to update the WSDL to process a response

Tags: web-services, soap, xsd, wsdl, cxf

Let's have a simple WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.test.com"
    xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.test.com">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.test.com">
            <xs:element name="sessionId" type="xs:string">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="transactionId" type="xs:string">
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="Login">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="userId" type="xs:string">
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="pwd" type="xs:string">
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="LoginResponse">
                <xs:complexType />
            </xs:element>
        </xs:schema>
    </wsdl:types>
    <wsdl:message name="Login">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="Login"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="LoginResponse">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="LoginResponse"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="HeaderSessionId">
        <wsdl:part name="header" element="sessionId"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:message name="HeaderTransactionId">
        <wsdl:part name="header" element="transactionId"/>
    </wsdl:message>
    <wsdl:portType name="MMCServicesPort"> 
        <wsdl:operation name="Login"> 
            <wsdl:input message="Login"/>  
            <wsdl:output message="LoginResponse"/>  
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:portType>
    <wsdl:binding name="MMCServicesBinding" type="MMCServicesPort">
        <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>  
        <wsdl:operation name="Login">
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:header message="HeaderSessionId" part="header" use="literal"/>
                <soap:body use="literal" />
            </wsdl:output> 
        </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
    <wsdl:service name="MMCServicesService">
        <wsdl:port name="MMCServicesService" binding="MMCServicesBinding">
            <soap:address location="/test"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

For this WSDL the following message is a valid response:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
       xmlns:test="http://www.test.com">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <test:sessionId>xxx</test:sessionId>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <test:LoginResponse/>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What/How do I need to change the WSDL to accept the following message as the Login operation response message instead:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <sessionId xmlns="http://www.test.com">xxx</sessionId>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <LoginResponse/>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

...the LoginResponse is w/o a namespace definition.

I have a WS with unknown WSDL which doesn't provide the WSDL. The one above has been somehow reconstructed by someone else in the history. However the real WS which I need to use provides the 2nd response which is however refused by the Apache CXF java library.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The core issue seems to come with the definition of targetNamespace

in your code:

`<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://www.test.com">`

when replaced with:

`<xs:schema targetNamespace="">`

the SOAP XML should be without any prefix.

It might require also define the empty or default namespace at the wsdl:binding and wsdl:service level:

`<wsdl:binding name="MMCServicesBinding" type="MMCServicesPort" xmlns="">
...
<wsdl:service name="MMCServicesService" xmlns="">`

You might have built some code stubs based on that WSDL then you have to update also this generated code.